# PDM.Rootshell behaviour detected in my clean application by my antivirus

Tags: java, antivirus, virus

I have built a Java SWING application and my Kaspersky antivirus detects that it has behaviour similar to PDM.Rootshell and shows me an warning. What does this mean? How can I solve this?
My clients will not be happy if they see this.

Comment: wow... never heard that one before

Answer (score 1):

http://forum.kaspersky.com/index.php?showtopic=190845 
has this suggestion

If the detection is from a known application, and the application is from the official source, then you can ignore it and/or Allow it/right click the detection and Add to exclusions.

I had same problem with mxmlc of Adobe Flex 4.6 SDK

Search Google (with quotes)
"How to add a trusted application to the list of exclusions of Proactive Defense in Kaspersky"
You may add your application as trusted

Jayanta@Kolkata